# I have used jplayer to play mp3 song, and i want to play next and previous song. How should i do this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

please give any idea how to play next song and prious song...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-09-Partir.mp3"
            }).jPlayer('play');
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

Comment: Or how should i find out the current id or song name which is currently play?

Comment: Can you tell me name of plugin that you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#aElement').click(function(e){
  $.getJSON('/forwardsong', null, function(res) {
    // currentSong = res.mp3;
    // updateView(currentSong);
    $('#jquery_jplayer').jPlayer(
      'setMedia',
      { mp3: 'http://blabalabla.bla' + currentSong.url }).jPlayer('play');
    });
 });
```

that is the idea: use AJAX

have fun:)